# Character misbehaving in SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, collation

I am having an issue with some select statements, or more precisely what they return.

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a name field (Kanji Characters) that are blank, using where clauses like the following:

```
name IS NULL OR name = ''
```

I know there are other ways to do this and I have tried those but this returns what I need except for this.

```
䑓
```

When I search the database using the above character it returns itself and rows that are blank. No other characters seem to behave in this way.

It has been suggested that it might be a Collation issue. The columns collation is set to Latin_General_CI_AS.

Really just looking for a reason as to why a single character would behave differently to all the others.

If more information is required, please ask.

Comment: If I'm right Latin1-General is codepage windows-1252. All characters in this codepage are listed here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/windows-1252/list.htm - so I think the Kanji characters are split in multiple characters that match CP1252. Possibly even outside the valid character range.

Comment: Curious. `SELECT 1 WHERE N'䑓' = N''` indeed returns `1`. `SELECT 1 WHERE N'䑓' = N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2` does not, of course. But even `COLLATE Japanese_CI_AS` considers this blank. `COLLATE Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_140_CS_AI` does not, on my machine. (However that works -- I'm no expert in Japanese collations.) You can test for "true blankness" with `DATALENGTH = 0`, but I'm pretty sure that can't be used in an index seek. It might when *combined* with `= N''`.

Comment: If you do `name = N''`? How does it  behave?

Comment: @tukan It returns all the blanks and that character.

Comment: @JimmyPop13 then you have to play around with the collations - https://dimantdatabasesolutions.blogspot.com/2010/10/sometimes-it-is-important-to-choose.html

Comment: @JeroenMostert The COLLATE with Latin1 seems to have solved my issues. Gunna test a bit further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: On SQL Server 2012 (which is old enough for my purposes) `WHERE col IS NULL OR (col = N'' AND col = N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2)` will still use an index on the column (using just the `_BIN2` will not). YMMV, but this seems like a promising approach.

Answer (score -1):

why not try

```
isnull(name, '') = ''
```

update

```
isnull(nullif(name, '䑓'), '') = ''
```

Comment: That's just a worse performing version of `WHERE Name = '' OR NAME IS NULL`, and doesn't fix the underlying problem. `ISNULL(N'䑓', '') = ''` is still true.